# Ubuntu 19.10/18.04 key-binding bug

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, 19.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 19.10. Worked as expected. I login this morning and begin typing. Several keys seem to have bound to each other. In particular the following happens:

- When I type the 'i' key the output is 'pi'. The output is the same when I type 'p'.
- typing k results in ';k' as does typing ';'

There are numerous other messed up keys but typing this is proving difficult due to the keyboard bug. I'm chuckling to myself because it's so difficult to type.

I fresh installed with 18.04 and the same problem occurred. 
This situation has arose only this morning.

Comment: Have you tried the keyboard on a different computer, or a different keyboard on this computer, in order to confirm that this is not caused by a faulty keyboard?

Comment: I do not have the means to do that. Thpis pis very strange. It started hapipienping just thpis mornping. EXAMPLE!

Comment: it could be that though... not sure how else to rule out a faulty keyboard. Maybe try to create and boot a live USB with some other Linux distributions, and if this problem persists or not.

Comment: It very well could be the keyboard to be honest. I have been spraying it down lately with anti-bacterial spray due to COVID-19. Maybe some got underneath? Or the wiping down caused damage? Seems unlikely but possible.

Comment: So in that case how does one fix a keyboard? Lenovo X230 Thinkpad.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/9w2cea/weird_keyboard_issue_on_x230/

Comment: Miraculously the issue has resolved itself. Thank you all who considered my issue.

Comment: I won't speculate as to why this has resolved itself. But thanks in particular to Logix for answering.

Comment: How do I close this question of now it has been resolved?

Comment: you're supposed to select an answer as the correct one for your question, but since these are just comments, and there's no answer (and you don't know how it was fixed), you can't...